# How to calculate the number of possible passwords for Ansdersons Formula

Tags: computer-science

I have an exam tomorrow on this. My lecturer has put the following in lecture notes: "The number of one- to five-character passwords that can be obtained using elements from a set containing $n > 0$ characters is $N = n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + n^5$.".

It was going all fine until the point I was going through past exams yesterday and there was a question(derived from the whole section): calculate the number of possible codes in a $4$ digit pins. Using the above formula it gives me $10+10^2+10^3+10^4 = 11110$. Which is incorrect and the answer should be $10000$.

Now I am extremely lost and my lecturer is not responding to my emails. What scenarios the above formula is usable for? Why does it not work with pins but works for questions like these: "Password characters may be any ASCII characters from $1$ to $127$, inclusive."

Comment: Your instructor's formula pertains to "one- to five-character passwords."  That is, it counts passwords of length between one and five. The problem of interest, by contrast, requires that there are _exactly_ four characters.

Comment: Please format your questions. The most basic point is that formulae need to be enclosed between $.

Comment: @semiclassical What about making your comment an answer?